# Accessing network drive in VisualSVN server post commit hook

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am using VisualSVN Server on windows 7 and I wish to write a post-commit hook script to back up my repository to a network shared drive automatically on each new commit. I am using the `svnadmin hotcopy` command from svn commandline which seems to be working correctly, but when I insert the same command within the post-commit hook script it fails with the error - `svn-error-e720005`.

I understand that this is due to some access permissions with the VisualSVN Server and would like to know what is to be done so that the VisualSVN Server is able to access and read/write to network shared folders / drives.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this!

If you want a per-commit backup, [use repository replication with `svnsync`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/maint/#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication). Put the call to sync in your post-commit hook and let it handle things. Otherwise, your problem will be down to the user that SVNServer is running as. Change it to your user and see if that works.

Comment: Do you mean to say I should be setting up backup svn server and sync that with the primary svn server instead of just backing up the repository? Since the syntax of svnsync is: svnsync synchronize DEST_URL SOURCE_URL

Comment: I used svnsync but its again giving the same issue, when the command is issued from command prompt it works fine and commits all revisions but when the same command is inserted within the post-commit hook, svn client hangs after committing, what could be the reason for this?